# how do you access a IIFE and print to document

Tags: javascript, html

I'ma beginner and ina tutorial i learned about IIFE when i did an exercise to get the grips i found an "error".I want to write a IIFE variable to the document ust like you would if it was a regular function but i get a blank document. I tried to google a solution but there was none.this is my exercise:

```
(function() {
  let age = 50;
  return age;
})();
document.write(age);
```

Comment: `let age = (function() { ... })();`

Comment: Or just put the `document.write()` call inside the IIFE.

Comment: i'll try thanks alot

Comment: Also read up more on variable scope in javascript particularly in regards to `let`. That will explain the "why" behind the answers/comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let v = (function() {
  let age = 50;
  return age;
})();
document.write(v);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.